# posix shell script: recursively remove all files starting with a certain prefix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to use a shell script to remove recursively all files starting with the prefix `._` (matching the pattern `._*`) in a certain directory, but the embarrassing thing is that I barely know anything about shell scripting except the very basic. Could anyone be kind enough to write one for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ find <DIRNAME> -type f -name '._*' -delete`

- `<DIRNAME>` -- the root directory.
- `-type f` -- only regular files, not directories (if that's what you want).
- `-delete` -- what to do with the files (delete them) (if omitted, will print file names)

Comment: Note that `-delete` is a non-standard GNU extension (although one you should use if available). For other versions of `find`, you'll need `find <DIRNAME> -type f -name '._*' -exec rm '{}' +`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ find the_directory -name "._*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: OP want remove only files ;) don't be drastic ;) :)

Comment: Arguably, directories in a Unix system are kind of files, too.

Comment: sure, everything is a file ;) but OPs who ask this type of questions probably don't know this - and probably don't want remove recursively directories ;) :)

Comment: all right, you must be right, I guess that's why shx2's answer was better and accepted as correct, I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command can be used to find all files within a tree that match certain predicates and operate upon them.